# Declaring const for parameter assignment

Tags: flutter, dart

To the extend I know, declaring a value `const`, makes it immutable and can't be changed after declaration. But suppose I have this widget:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(height: 200),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey),
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
    child: Image.asset(
      _assetPath,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  );
}
```

does assigning `padding` value of `const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10)` differ with `EdgeInsets.only(left: 10)`? Is it for the `canonicalized` purposes?

Comment: As far as I know it is good practice to make const to something what will not change. You can have an inline condition in your padding which then it would not work with const. I personally don't use const in this cases. It might make a little difference in memory usage but I don't care. It just adds extra letters in my codes.

Comment: So as I guessed, it's for ``canonicalized`` purposes. which means it gets evaluated at compile-time and any future evaluation, the calculated value would be returned. So for something like ``EdgeInsets.only(left: 10 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/1920)`` can't be declared ``const`` but ``EdgeInsets.only(left: 10)`` can be.

Answer (score 1):

If you're designing for only one screen size, then you can get away with using `const`. But if you're designing for multiple screen sizes, like for mobile and web, then you definitely don't want to use `const` instead, something like

```
padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/1920)
```

to ensure that your padding adapts to the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely doesn’t make any difference in you application output.

According to me it is really good practice to make values constant which are not going to change because it helps to improve performance.

const value define at compile time that’s why it improve performance.